# How to minimize dependency for a simple website using an interface

Tags: php, class, oop, interface

I would like to use an interface for database.php, since the database object is currently hard coded in session's constructor. I see a problem with including database.php in index.php since I dont want index to depend on database...?

But since index.php is including session.php I figured that the creation of the session object should be left to index, and not have index rely on it's creation somewhere else, such as creating the session object at the bottom of session.php. What am I not seeing here, and how can I create the least amount of dependency with a newly created iDatabase.php that the Database class implements. Thank you in advance, as I am open to any kind of advice that can help me out.

Here is how my files are currently

```
//index.php
<?php
include('session.php');
$session = new Session();
?>
<html>
...
</html>
```

---

```
//session.php
<?php
include('database.php');

class Session {

    private $db;

    function __construct() {
    $this->db = new Database();
    }
}
?>
```

---

```
//database.php
class Database {
...
}
```

---

This is what I'd like to do...

```
//index.php
include('database.php');
include('session.php');
$database = new Database();
$session = new Session($database);
<html>
...
</html>
```

---

```
//session.php

class Session {

    private $db;

    public function __construct(iDatabase $database) {
        $this->db = $database;
    } 
}
```

---

```
//database.php
include('iDatabase.php');

class Database implements iDatabase {
... 
}
```

Comment: If you want index.php to use your database file, you have to include database.php in your file. Don't look at this as something bad, it's very common and there's very few ways to get around it.

Comment: @Alex L - Ok cool, I edited my post to give you an idea of where I'm thinking of leaning with this. What do you think and what ways are you referring to, when you said around it?

Comment: it looks like you're headed in the right direction, except I'm not sure why you insist on using interfaces for this application. Do you plan on having multiple types of database objects? One method to get around these requires is the [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function.